# OpenCV thickness when drawing rectangle too thick

Tags: opencv, python

I want to draw a rectangle but the smallest thickness which is 1 still too thick for me, how do i fix this?

here's my code

```
img_rgb = cv2.imread('CS111/img/a5_of_heart.png')

img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_rgb, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

template = cv2.imread("CS111/img/heart_of_5.png",0)
h, w = template.shape[::] 
res = cv2.matchTemplate(img_gray, template, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
threshold = 0.5
loc = np.where( res >= threshold)
for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
    cv2.rectangle(img_rgb, pt, (pt[0] + w, pt[1] + h), (0, 255, 0), 1)
img_rgb = cv2.resize(img_rgb,(800,600))
cv2.imshow("Matched image", img_rgb)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image]

Comment: Thickness must be a non-negative integer, so `1` is the smallest thickness, you can get. Why don't you resize the image first, and then draw the rectangles using adapted coordinates? For example, you have some image of size `(100, 200)` and the points' coordinates. You resize your image to `(200, 400)`, so your "scaling factor" is `2`. Then, just multiply the points' coordinates by `2`, so you get the right rectangles.

Comment: i can't because i'm matching template, if i resize the original image then i can't matching from the given template

Comment: After matching templates, before generating the output image...

Answer (score 0):

Thickness in cv2.rectangle is right. It means that the template matching found several rectangles at the same time. That is why the rectangle thickness seems to be too thick.

You need to apply non-maximum suppression. That will solve your problem.